# Searching with one of multiple tags

Tags: support, tag-search

**TL;DR**
Given multiple tags, how can I search with *OR* between them (and not *AND*)?

**Use case:**
I'd like to search for questions that are tagged in at least one tag out of a list of tags.
Using multiple tags to get questions that have *all* the tags can be done like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm+node.js

I'm looked at the [searching page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), but unfortanely didn't find anything there.

Ideas?